# Existence of "half-open interval parametrization" for metric measure spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be a Polish space, and let $\mu$ be a non-zero finite Borel measure on $X$ (the metric measure space $(X, \mu)$ is called a Lebesbue-Rokhlin space by Gromov in [1]).

> In the beginning of Chapter $3 \frac{1}{2}_+$ in [1], Gromov mentions the "isomorphism theorem" for such metric measure spaces (namely that $(X, \mu)$ is isomorphic to a closed interval equipped with the Lebesgue measure, with a countable extra points with non-zero measure in the case that $\mu$ has atoms). He then proceeds to define the metric $\Box_\lambda$ between such metric measure spaces.

> The full definition of this metric is not necessary for the purpose of this question. However, in defining this metric, Gromov makes the remark that there always exists a "parametrization" of $(X, \mu)$, that is, a measurable map $$ \varphi : [0, m) \to X,$$
> where $m = \mu(X)$, for which $\varphi_*dx = \mu$, which must be surjective up to sets of measure zero, and which can be chosen bijective if $X$ has no atoms.

Now, I see why such a map always exists when $\mu$ has no atoms (one can just consider the map given by the isomorphism theorem mentioned above), but I do not see why this exists in general. I also do not see why the map can be chosen to be bijective when $\mu$ has no atoms; even the map from the isomorphism theorem is not surjective in this case.

Moreover, why is the "parametrization" considered on the half-open interval instead of the closed interval?

$[1]$ M. Gromov, Metric structures for Riemannian and non-Riemannian spaces, English translation

Comment: For your first question, you can check Takashi Shioya's Metric Measure Geometry book (available on arXiv). That any metric measure space has a parametrization is proven in Lemma 4.2, using the isomorphism theorem.